# Get Error 403 Image Angular

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, servicestack

Server response to me document(in Json) with information. And in this json i have a url to image. And every time when i load new content of page( with new image) it appear but in console have error:

[image]

I use url from json in angular to display image on my website.

More info from fiddler:
[image]

Screen in chrome loaded image: 
[image]

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: IE didnt show this error, only chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `src` attribute Set `ng-src` in your html markup whereever you are binding the url to json response. Something like

```
<img ng-src="{{content.imageUrl}}"/>
```

Using `src` causes browser to make a request before binding is resolved.

More details [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ng-src to prevent the browser from fetching the image before the {{content.imageURL}} resolved by Angular.

More information from ng-src docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc